# How to get month number using the conditions in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select

I have below query in which for some `security_typ` field i am getting the correct value starting from month name for field `Name` but some `security_type` field the value is not starting from month name or there is no month name provided in that for field `Name`.

```
select distinct UPPER(SUBSTR(name, 0, instr(name,' ', 1, 1) - 1)) name, 
t.SECURITY_TYP as SECURITY_TYP, t.OPT_EXPIRE_DT 
from BB_EQUOPT_IMPORT t WHERE 1 = 1;
```

[image]

Now i want to set the value in field `MONAT` which is number data type such that if the value is starting from field `NAME` is month name from January till December then set it to their month number for example if the starting name is August then set it to 8.

If the starting name is not any month from January till Decemeber as we can see for `securtiy_typ` 'Financial index option' then take the month from field OPT_EXPIRY_DT and set it in `MONAT` field.

Currently in my select query i am using below condition to get the month number from `Name` field and setting it for field `MONAT` and i want to modify this select query:

```
Select to_number(TO_CHAR(to_date(UPPER(SUBSTR(name, 0, instr(name,' ', 1, 1) - 1)),'MONTH',
    'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American'),'MM')) monat from BB_EQUOPT_IMPORT
```

Below is the desired result i want:
[image]

Comment: Having a desired result would help a lot.

Comment: i have added desired result

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: i am using oracle 18c

Comment: month name is actually i am not using in my table ...its just to show the result i am putting there

Comment: Can the name column contain a valid month different from the month in opt_expiry_date? In your sample data this is never the case, so you could just **always** extract the month from opt_expiry_date.

Comment: yes just extract the month from opt_expiry_date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN UPPER(SUBSTR(name, 0, instr(name,' ', 1, 1) - 1)) NOT IN ('JANUARY', 'FEBRUARY', 'MARCH', 'APRIL', 'MAY', 'JUNE', 'JULY', 'AUGUST', 'SEPTEMBER','OCTOBER','NOVEMBER','DECEMBER') 
      THEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(opt_expiry_date, 'MM')) 
      ELSE 
         DECODE(UPPER(SUBSTR(name, 0, instr(name,' ', 1, 1) - 1)), 'JANUARY', 1, 'FEBRUARY', 2, 'MARCH', 3, 'APRIL', 4, 'MAY', 5, 'JUNE', 6, 'JULY', 7, 'AUGUST', 8, 'SEPTEMBER', 9, 
                      'OCTOBER', 10, 'NOVEMBER', 11, 'DECEMBER', 12, -1) END as MONAT
FROM bb_equoptimport
```

Comment: i am getting -1 as a result which is not valid month number and also in name field the value is coming for example 'January X45TO' and thats why i am checking  the first string from this field whethere its month name or not

Comment: Use: UPPER(SUBSTR(name, 0, instr(name,' ', 1, 1) - 1)) for the name field as in your example.

Comment: thanks its working but just a small change can u please also use NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American like i mention in my select query as this is very important as i am getting data from America and OPT_EXPIRY_DATE field is date field so why to_char ?

Comment: this solution is already valid for america, I do TO_CHAR first to extract the month from the DATE, you can't do: TO_NUMBER(sysdate, 'MM') directly, you can also use extract as the other users.

Comment: just one question will there be performance issue as i am using this logic in View ? i have like 1935486 rows in this view

Answer (score 4):

You can use a case expression to decide which column to get the month value from:

```
select name, security_typ, opt_expiry_dt,
  case when security_typ = 'Equity Option' then
    extract(month from to_date(name, 'MONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'))
  else
    extract(month from opt_expiry_dt)
  end as monat
from BB_EQUOPT_IMPORT;
```

or:

```
select name, security_typ, opt_expiry_dt,
  extract(month from
    case when security_typ = 'Equity Option' then
      to_date(name, 'MONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
    else
      opt_expiry_dt
    end
  ) as monat
from BB_EQUOPT_IMPORT;
```

I've simplified the conversion of the month-name string to a date, and used `extract()` as mentioned in the answers to your previous question. Although looking at the first query in your question again that suggests the name always has other text after the month, in which case you could still simplify a bit to:

```
to_date(substr(name, 1, instr(name, ' ') - 1), 'MONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
```

Demo with some sample data in a CTE:

```
with BB_EQUOPT_IMPORT (name, security_typ, opt_expiry_dt) as (
  select 'JANUARY ', 'Equity Option', date '2020-01-20' from dual
  union all
  select 'MAY', 'Equity Option', date '2020-05-18' from dual
  union all
  select 'MICEX', 'Financial index option.', date '2019-11-21' from dual
  union all
  select 'SX5E', 'Financial index option.', date '2020-12-18' from dual
)
select name, security_typ, opt_expiry_dt,
  case when security_typ = 'Equity Option' then
    extract(month from to_date(name, 'MONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'))
  else
    extract(month from opt_expiry_dt)
  end as monat
from BB_EQUOPT_IMPORT;

NAME     SECURITY_TYP            OPT_EXPIRY      MONAT
-------- ----------------------- ---------- ----------
JANUARY  Equity Option           2020-01-20          1
MAY      Equity Option           2020-05-18          5
MICEX    Financial index option. 2019-11-21         11
SX5E     Financial index option. 2020-12-18         12
```

or the second way, and with more text after the month names:

```
with BB_EQUOPT_IMPORT (name, security_typ, opt_expiry_dt) as (
  select 'JANUARY FOO', 'Equity Option', date '2020-01-20' from dual
  union all
  select 'MAY BAR', 'Equity Option', date '2020-05-18' from dual
  union all
  select 'MICEX', 'Financial index option.', date '2019-11-21' from dual
  union all
  select 'SX5E', 'Financial index option.', date '2020-12-18' from dual
)
select name, security_typ, opt_expiry_dt,
  extract(month from
    case when security_typ = 'Equity Option' then
      to_date(substr(name, 1, instr(name, ' ') - 1), 'MONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
    else
      opt_expiry_dt
    end
  ) as monat
from BB_EQUOPT_IMPORT;

NAME        SECURITY_TYP            OPT_EXPIRY      MONAT
----------- ----------------------- ---------- ----------
JANUARY FOO Equity Option           2020-01-20          1
MAY BAR     Equity Option           2020-05-18          5
MICEX       Financial index option. 2019-11-21         11
SX5E        Financial index option. 2020-12-18         12
```

---

If you can't identify a fixed list of `security_typ` values to use in the case expression, another option - since you're on 18c - is to use [the default clause from `to_date()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html), with `coalesce()`:

```
with BB_EQUOPT_IMPORT (name, security_typ, opt_expiry_dt) as (
  select 'JANUARY FOO', 'Equity Option', date '2020-01-20' from dual
  union all
  select 'MAY BAR', 'Equity Option', date '2020-05-18' from dual
  union all
  select 'MICEX', 'Financial index option.', date '2019-11-21' from dual
  union all
  select 'SX5E', 'Financial index option.', date '2020-12-18' from dual
)
select name, security_typ, opt_expiry_dt,
  extract(month from
    coalesce(
      to_date(substr(name, 1, instr(name, ' ') - 1) default null on conversion error,
        'MONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'),
      opt_expiry_dt
    )
  ) as monat
from BB_EQUOPT_IMPORT;

NAME        SECURITY_TYP            OPT_EXPIRY      MONAT
----------- ----------------------- ---------- ----------
JANUARY FOO Equity Option           2020-01-20          1
MAY BAR     Equity Option           2020-05-18          5
MICEX       Financial index option. 2019-11-21         11
SX5E        Financial index option. 2020-12-18         12
```

If the `to_date()` call gets an error, because the first word of the name is not an English month name (or for any other reason), then that function call evaluates to null. The `coalesce()` will see that null result and use the `opt_expiry_dt` instead. Either way you end up with a valid date, and then extract the month number from that.

---

Of course, if the `name` value is always actually going to be the name of the month in `opt_expiry_dt` anyway, then this decision isn't necessary and you can just always use that date, as @ThorstenKettner said. I'd assumed looking at the name was important, but it seems that it is not...

Comment: this is hard coded and i have thousands of different name options which is not starting from month name itself

Comment: I'm only using the name at all for 'Equity Option'. Or do you mean there are lots of `security_typ` values which might have month names, not just that one? Still too many to list in the case expression? I've added an 18c-friendly way to not need to know the names and rely on the conversion failing...

Comment: @Andrew - the conversion error query I added is probably the simplest way to do this for 18c (or 12cR2, it doesn't work before that) - *if* you actually need to look at that month name at all. It doesn't seem like you do need to, if it always matches the expiry date's month anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As you say that the name column cannot contain a valid month that is different from the month in opt_expiry_date, you can completely ignore the name column and just always extract the month from opt_expiry_date:

```
select name, security_typ, opt_expiry_date, extract(month from opt_expiry_date) as monat
from bb_equopt_import;
```